# what is the meaning of char *s={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}; in C and how it is different from char *s="hello";?

Tags: c

`char *s={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};` --- gives a warning saying:

```
warning: (near initialization for ‘s’)
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
```

But `char *s="hello";` displays hello by allocating memory space for 6 characters in read only memory and s pointing to that specific location.

But what exactly is `char *s={'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};` and how it is different?

Comment: `{ … }` is not itself an array, it's a braced initializer list. `char *s = { 'h', 'e', … }` is trying to initialize a pointer with the character `'h'` and discards the rest of the characters. (but all this can be deduced merely from the error message.)

Answer (score 2):

A string literal like `"hello"` is treated as a pointer-to-char or an array-of-char depending on how you use it.

```
char *s = "hello";    // treats the string literal as pointer-to-char
char s[] = "hello";   // treats the string literal as array-of-char
```

An initializer like `{'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}` is treated as an array. It cannot be assigned to a pointer.

```
char *s = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};   // this is NOT valid
char s[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};  // same as char s[] = "hello"
```

Comment: `treats the string literal as pointer-to-char` – no it doesn't, a string literal is always an array of `char`. It's just that arrays usually decay into pointers, and initialization of a pointer with an array is no exception.

Comment: You are correct from a language lawyer point of view. But sometimes lawyer-speak obfuscates rather than illuminates. To my way of thinking, saying that *"it's an array that decays to a pointer"* is the same as saying that it's *"treated as a pointer"*. All I did was skip the intermediate step, and get right to the point.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the `"hello"` is a string literal and `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` is a initializer list. The meaning of assigning a `char*` to a string literal is to just make the pointer point at the string, while the meaning of assigning `char*` to a initializer list is to just assign it to the first value (which is `'h'` converted to a `char*`).

The proper way to use the initializer list is to use a `char` array instead:

```
char s[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

but still there is a difference here as this way you should end up with a mutable buffer. Here the initializer list is used as a list of values to initialize the element in the array with. It's a shortcut for:

```
char s[6];

s[0] = 'h';
s[1] = 'e';
s[2] = 'l';
s[3] = 'l';
s[4] = 'o';
s[5] = '\0';
```

Comment: "the meaning of...is to just assign it to the first value" - in Standard C it is *ill-formed*. Pointers may have at most one initializer.  The behaviour you're describing is  GCC extension.

Comment: Also a gcc extension is that `'h'` is treated as `(char *)'h'`

Comment: @M.M Your second comment I would say is incorrect. Both cases seem to be accepted by MSVC as well (so if they're extensions they are not very GCC specific).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *s1 = "hello";                  /* creates a string literal   */
    char s2[] = {'h','e','l','l','o',0}; /* creates a character array  */

    printf ("\n s1 : %s\n s2 : %s\n\n", s1, s2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/s1s2

 s1 : hello
 s2 : hello
```

The primary difference between the *character array* `'s2'` and *string literal* `'s1'` is that the *string literal* is created and cannot later be changed. The character array can be used as any other array or null-terminated string.

Comment: it's not guaranteed that a string literal be placed in readonly memory; in fact, not even the existence of any sort of "readonly memory" is something the language is concerned with.

Comment: I was talking from the dump for the file to assembly and the "hello" being happily in the *.rodata* section.

Comment: @DavidCRankin there's no assembly either in the question or in your answer whatsoever. This is a C language question which is about an abstract language construct that has nothing to do with assembly; consequently you are supposed to answer it from a C language point of view, and not from an assembly point of view. Infiltrating useless implementation details adds no value and only causes confusion, it doesn't clear it.

Comment: Not worth the fight over semantics.

Comment: In C terms, writing over a string literal would be "undefined behavior".